# Collecting data (Machine learning)

Tags: python

How can I collect the value after the for loop condition is satisfied? For example, I would like to get 416 instead of 394 in this case.

Here is what I have done so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_obama = pd.read_csv(Facebookobama_path)

Frame_obama = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Time Slice_Obama"])

for x in Frame_obama:
    j = 0
    TimeSlice_list_obama_TS1 = []

    while j<len(df_obama):
        Frame_obama["Time Slice_Obama"] = pd.Series(df_obama.iloc[j].values[1:])
        if Frame_obama["Time Slice_Obama"].values[-1] != -1:
            i = Frame_obama[Frame_obama["Time Slice_Obama"] >= 0].values[0]
        else:
            len(Frame_obama["Time Slice_Obama"])

        j += 1
        TimeSlice_list_obama_TS1.append(i)
```

Many thanks!

[image: Data_Set]

Comment: Which variable? All the variables will have the values that were set at the last iteration. So you can just print it

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I am trying to do the same thing for 80k+ data :/